# How can I change the wireless pasword from the terminal?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, command-line

Hello I've recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 and entered a wrong password for my apartment's wireless network.

Upon entering the network options to edit the password it will allow me to delete it and rewrite but not to save,the save edit button disappears.

I have already tried deleting and recreating the connection but it starts up with the incorrect password already in,also restarting both my wirelesses and laptop have failed.

I feel I'm forgetting some permissions or something and that I should be able to change it from the terminal.

I will accept any solutions but please don't suggest upgrade to the newest edition there's a reason I'm running the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Alt+F2, try running `gksudo nm-connection-editor`. That should allow you to edit and save everything.

Comment: If `nm-connection-editor` does not exist try just `nm-editor`, I know the command exist just don't know if they changed the name of it on further releases. gl and drop a comment if both do not exist :S

Comment: `sudo nm-connection-editor`   still works as of Ubuntu 21.04 ... another way is to `cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`  and then find file matching your wifi network then edit that file for example  `sudo vi myNetworkName`   then edit value for key `psk` under tag `[wifi-security]`

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can do a telnet to a wireless device from your local network. However, they don't all support it, they often use a non conventional port, and you need a login and password... the password is probably the one you know of already. The login should be the same as the HTTP login.

So you'd do something like this:

```
telnet 192.168.0.254 888
```

to connect, and it should ask you for the login and password. The IP and port should be available / shown in the HTTP settings somewhere if it is at all supported.