# How to change wireless password from text mode?

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line, gnome-terminal

I searched for other answers and came up with this, [How can I change the wireless pasword from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73873/how-can-i-change-the-wireless-pasword-from-the-terminal)

It uses `gksudo`, but I want to do it in text mode of Ubuntu. i.e no graphics.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

The wireless network configuration files are saved in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory. The passwords are kept in these configuration files.

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
ls
sudo nano network_name
```

Or, simple:

```
sudo nano $(locate network_name)
```